# Right way to call image from css

Tags: css, text, alignment

Newbie here, need help.

I'm trying to call an an image from css. Is this the right way to do?

```
<span class="mapicon">blah blah blah</span>
```

Using the above, I can't align the image to my text correctly.

```
<span class="mapicon"></span>blah blah blah
```

This one works for me but is this the way to do it?

My css

```
.mapicon {
background-image: url('http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/map_icon.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 15px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call", can you clarify what your issue is? Have you considered not doing this in CSS, but using a standard `<img>` tag? That may be the way to go

Comment: I've tried the <img> tag to display the icon beside my text but I'm adding like dozens and dozens of them. I thought of doing it once via css.

Answer (score 0):

I should to it by the next way ;

HTML

```
<p><span class="mapicon">&nbsp;</span>blah blah blah</p>
```

that you wrap the text in a paragraph and that you can replace the content in span.mapicon with an image through css.

The css code is then,

```
.mapicon {
    background-image: url('http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/map_icon.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    /* image width and height */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

i hope that this has helped you